# how to permanantly change boot order in UEFI os manger list?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi

how to change the boot order in a UEFI-based dual windows/ubuntu install , usually UEFI system boots directly to windows (I experienced this with HP 15) although i made a lot of changes to make it boot to grub using BIOS , i couldn't find a way to make it do so

Comment: I'm just so glad I have removed windows from my system.

Comment: i agree, I’m planning to so in the coming days, hh but there are some people who really find it hard to let it go!!! for me I'm adopting an OSS philosphy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this [post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Changing-Boot-Order-on-Dual-Boot-Windows-8-and-Ubuntu/td-p/2503733) on the HP support forum, it is not particular to HP as it doesn't depend on hardware in any step.

so the steps are as follows:

1- In Windows , run cmd.exe as an administrator

2 -mount the UEFI partition using : `mountvol X: /S`

change X with a drive letter of your choice

2- now kill the explorer and re-execute it, using

```
Taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe 
explorer.exe
```

3- the new mount new mount partition should appear in the "My computer" window
    go to X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\ where X is the the Drive letter you specified before, and rename the file `bootmgfw.efi` to something like `bootmgfw.efi~`
and remove the file X:\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi.

4- in the command prompt execute

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\[FILENAME]`

note that this require administrative rights and the name of the `FILENAME` is to be adapted with previous renaming, in this example it is `bootmgfw.efi~`

5- to make things clearer, you can change the Windows Boot loader to something like "Fixed Windows path" with the command

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} description "Fixed Windows path"
```

6- on Ubuntu, Use efibootmgr to delete the "OS boot Manager" entry:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

7- use `sudo efibootmgr -l` to learn the id of each UEFI boot menu entry if you had ubuntu on boot0001 and windows on boot0002 so proceed like this

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0001,0002
```

8- use  `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add the following block in the file

```
menuentry "Microsoft Windows 7" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        insmod search_fs_uuid
        insmod chain
        set root='XXXXXX'
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/[FILENAME]
}
```

where XXXXXX is the output of `sudo grub-probe -t drive /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/[FILENAME]`

and FILENAME is the efi file name, in this example it is `bootmgfw.efi~`

9- finally `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes , after reboot you should see the windows in the list while booting to Ubuntu by default via Grub.